# USB 2 cable causes clicking sound (and the device data not being able to be read) when connected to external HDDs

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

So I have this USB 2 cable, and it works fine with flash drives (tried with 2 different ones, both USB 2), but whenever I try to external HDDs to it, the HDD makes a clicking sound like it's turning off and on, and while the device shows up in the system tray, it doesn't show on "my computer". I tried this with 3 different external HDDs (all of which use USB 3), and all of them show this behavior (the HDDs work fine though when directly connected via their own cable and not via the extension cable).

So, my question is, I know this cable is somehow faulty, but what exactly is causing this behavior and why do the flash drives work fine (as far as I can tell at least)?

I use Windows 10.

Comment: are these HDDs externally powered?

Comment: They are powered via the USB cable. I've actually considered that the USB cable might provide insufficient power, maybe that's the case.

Comment: You should specify which size of external drive you are using.

Answer (score 0):

External HDDs use a lot of power, especially on spin-up and search, up to 1.5-2A, so the voltage along the cable sags if you are using junk extender, and the drive resets internally.

Flash drives usually do not use more than 200 - 500 mA, and are far less sensitive to bus voltage drops. This should be pretty obvious.

Comment: I suspected this, looking at the cable though, it should support 30V (which should be enough for a single external HDD) or so is written on it. I guess the cable is really junk though and the specification is wrong too.

Comment: if its a usb 2 cable, its also likely old and battered. its also possible that the issue is the usb port you are plugging into can't provide sufficient power. if you are jacking in to front usb ports, try one on the back of the box. those are directly connected to the mobo and usually have better power tolerances.

Comment: @Hormoz, 30-V cable rating has nothing to do with anything here. External HDDs use the standard 5V default USB output.